# mailing the junit reports in html format

Tags: html, css, junit, report, surefire

I am using maven site to create junit test reports. And I use maven postman plugin to mail the generated reports.
After running the maven site command the reports are generated with separate html and CSS files. In pom.xml I can specify which files to send in the mail.

My question: how do I mail the reports so that the CSS will be rendered in the mail body along with the html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I googled a lil and looks like a better way will be to create the reports in some different format like pdf which wont be having any formatting issues while sending mails.
I am experimenting with maven-pdf-plugin but this doesn't seem to work with maven 3+. Is there any other alternative?